# YOLO v8 creates forlder when training

Tags: yolo, yolov8

I d'like to disable option which creates folder with project name, weights, plots etc in every run. I've searched documentation bud didn't found anything. this is my code:

> model = YOLO('yolov8n.yaml').load('yolov8n.pt')
>
> model.train(data=f'{yolo_dataset_path}/dataset.yaml',
> batch=yolo_batch,
> workers=yolo_workers,
> epochs=yolo_epochs,
> patience = yolo_patience,
> imgsz = yolo_imgsz,
> save = yolo_save,
> device = yolo_device,
> project = project_name,
> verbose = yolo_verbose,
> seed = random_state
> )

I mean this folder

Comment: Train mode assumes saving the trained model somewhere for further use. You can keep every run in the same folder to avoid multiple folder creation by using an argument `exist_ok=True` with the unchanged project and experiment names.